# SELECT statement using max() function returning values from oldest row instead of matching row

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with three columns and several million rows of data.

**sensor_data**

```
sensor_id int PK
date datetime PK,
data decimal (10,3)
```

This query returns the most recent date for sensor 4, but the oldest data for sensor 4:

```
select max(date), data
from sensor_data
where sensor_id = 4;
```

These queries return correct values for data:

```
select date, data
from sensor_data
where sensor_id = 4
and date = (select max(date) from sensor_data where sensor_id = 4)
order by date desc;

select date, data
from sensor_data
where sensor_id = 4
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

I'm new to MySQL. Am I using `max()` wrong, or is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Allowing that query is a MySQLism, it's not really a valid SQL query. What it means is "get the max date and _any_ data from a row that matches the condition." Most if not all other RDBMS's reject the query entirely since you either have to use an aggregate function (a'la max/min) or a GROUP BY on any field that doesn't have an aggregate on it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: it's been a while, but I could swear this works in SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server fails with "Column 'sensor_data.data' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Ah, that error message rings a bell. Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sybase also has this relaxed feature, teradata as well under limited circumstances.

Comment: This is something of a FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to mixing aggregate functions with non-aggregate columns.  In PostgreSQL this would be an error, but in MySQL you get an arbitrary entry out of the rows used for the non-aggregate column value.

Comment: In mysql this behaviour is configurable via the sql mode setting of the server. Since mysql 5.7.5 the relaxed group by syntax is disabled by default, before that it was allowed by default. As the older installations get upgraded, we will hopefully see less of these questions.

Comment: @Shadow I had no idea bout it being "fixed" in newer MySQL. I can only say "hooray!" :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are not the only one, I would say :D

Answer (score 0):

You can just order your result by descending date:

```
SELECT data FROM sensor_data WHERE sensor_id = 4 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

As mentioned elsewhere, [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) is an aggregate function, meant to be used with [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).